# Datatables with fnDisplayRow

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

I am using .net MVC 4 and jquery DataTables 1.10.4

I am trying to highlight a row which 7th column is equal to @ViewBag.IdNumber, and that works fine when the row is on first page of my datatable.

How can I change the page of datatable so the highlighted row is displayad on page load.

My jquery code is:

```
      var selectedRow;
      var DataTable = $('.tableValute').DataTable({

       ...

        "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
            if (data[7] == "@ViewBag.IdNumber")
            {
                $('td', row).addClass('success');
                selectedRow = row.index;
            }
        }

       ...
    });

        DataTable.fnDisplayRow(selectedRow);
```

But in my console I get error:

DataTable.fnDisplayRow is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues

1. You **must** include the [plugin source](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnDisplayRow)
2. You **must** initialise the dataTable with oldschool `dataTable()` in order to make it work

But you can still have access to the API by using `api()`. Example

```
DataTable.fnDisplayRow( DataTable.api().row(16).node() );
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/nxyvmppb/**

Comment: I don't get error any more, but it simes to be as problem
because I display 10 rows by page and call 
DataTable.fnDisplayRow( DataTable.api().row(16).node() );

DataTable.api().row(16).node() returns null

only works when I call it 
DataTable.api().row(x).node() where x<= 10 it works,
but then it just stay on the same page